# Link to Google Maps Address from API

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

I'm working on http://2014naracup.com/. At the bottom, there is a Google Maps API integration through JavaScript and a map is displayed with a target address. When you click the addresss, for some reason the registration form opens. How can I correct this and have Google Maps link to the Address that is in the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u didnt close the a tag

```
<a href="http://form.jotformpro.com/form/42335568331959" target="_blank">
```

Comment: Ooops my mistake. I wasn't totally thinking about it